# Debuging SpringBatch application

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I have defined four steps in job ,JobExecution says completed, but i want to make sure  to know all my steps are getting called and executed properly or not.

**Do we have any way where i can debug each steps?**

Calling my batch job from RestController by defining an endpoint

Find Below the **configuration file**.

```
@Configuration
@Log4j2
public class PickUpBatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;


    @Bean
    public Job pickupJob() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("pickupJob")
            .listener(new JobResultListener())
            .start(a())
            .next(b())
            .next(c())
            .next(d())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step a() {
        System.out.println("PickUpBatchConfig.a");
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .Responsechunk(0)
            .reader(new One())//dummy ,does nothing in step1
            .processor(new Two())
            .writer(new Three())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step b() {
        System.out.println("PickUpBatchConfig.b");
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
            .Responsechunk(0)
            .reader(new Four())// Need to implement
            .processor(new Five())
            .writer(new Six())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step c() {
        System.out.println("PickUpBatchConfig.c");
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step3")
            .Responsechunk(0)
            .reader(new Seven())//need to implement
            .processor(new Eight())
            .writer(new nine())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step d() {
        System.out.println("PickUpBatchConfig.d");
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step4")
            .Responsechunk(0)
            .reader(new Ten())
            .processor(new Elevan())
            .writer(new Twelve())
            .build();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JobExecution says completed

If you get access to the job execution and are able to inspect its status, then you could get all step executions using `JobExecution#getStepExecutions` and inspect the status of each step.

Comment: yes i can user getStepExecutions Thanks  ,How will make sure all my reader,processor and writer are getting called in each step?

Comment: For each step execution, you can get the read count, write count, etc with `StepExecution#getReadCount`, `StepExecution#getWriteCount`..

Comment: What  we can conclude if suppose readcount = 0 and writeCount=0 in stepExecution

Comment: Please check this section: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#handlingStepCompletionWhenNoInputIsFound